# Is there a set procedure that allows us to extend a mathematical proof in geometry to $n$ dimension or is there a limitation?

Tags: geometry, proof-writing

> Is there a set procedure that allows us to extend a mathematical proof in geometry to $n$ dimension or is there a limitation?

By my Question, I meant that can we take a geometrical proof that applies for a space with $3$ dimensions and extend it for a space of any dimension through a set procedure that's easy to follow such that the person who goes through the procedure won't be credited for proving it for $n$ dimension, because it's as rudimentary as $2+2$? What are the things that prevent it from being true? I am thinking that it's not true, because a theorem that holds for a space with $3$ dimensions does not hold for a $1$ dimensional line or a $2$ dimensional plane.

Answer (score 1):

No, not in general. In geometry, a four-dimensional space is in a certain sense special, see e.g. [Why is four dimensions more difficult?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2808367/why-is-four-dimensions-more-difficult) or [What makes four dimensions special?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/47569/what-makes-four-dimensions-special)